# Page template that redirects user based on role

Tags: redirect, user-roles

I'm trying to come up with a wordpress page template (acting as a landing page) that redirects a user to another page based on their role.
ex. 
user with role editor goes to landing page and is redirected to "/editors-page/"
user with role subscriber goes to landing page and is redirected to "/subscribers-page/"

I've come across so many plugins and custom functions that talk about redirecting at login but I'm using multisite and there are some complications using any of those examples so I've landed on the above solution.

Any help would be wonderful! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `current_user_can()` to check the user roles. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

To check if the user is editor or administrator:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?>
    // Stuff here for administrators or editors
<?php } ?>
```

Then to redirect you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php):

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

Comment: This worked, sir!.  Thank you.

Comment: If this worked, please mark the answer with the checkmark or rate it up.